# How to split a dataset into two in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to split a dataset in pandas and eventually call this later to analyse it.

So far I have the following.

```
grouped_df = df.groupby(['Column_1','Column_2','Column_4'])
grouped_df.head()
```

But when I call `grouped_df.head()` it returns all 11 Columns. Can someone show me where I am going wrong?

Comment: `grouped_df.head()` does not do what you think it does. Groupby creates a `pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object` Calling `head` on the groupby object is not really different than calling `head` on your original df. The only difference is that you return the `head` for each group

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to use groupby, just mention df columns required while creating new df.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Column_1','Column_2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['Column_3','Column_4'])
```

Besides groupby isn't used to split columns, its used to split dataset into different groups.

Comment: Thankyou very much for clearing that up for me! Sorry it took so long for me to get back and check this post!

Comment: Does this solve your problem?  If yes accepting the answer and an upvote would be helpful.